# How to get cookie value in Js file in magento 1?

Tags: cookies, magento-1.9, jquery-cookie

I am trying to get cookie value but `"Mage.cookies"` is not working in js file, `How to get cookie value in js file in magento 1 ?`

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the `Mage/cookie.js` is loaded?
or is there any error Showing up in the Console?
or have you removed the `js.phtml` in the `layout/local.xml`?